# Using Triggers and Procedures to change active inventory

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, procedures

First starting with this table:

[Table estoque_folha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apESe.png)

And your records:

[Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjIeS.png)

My complete database code : pastebin.com/v30s9Aa1

I wanted to know how a trigger / procedure for when the *quantidade* field is zero, the line stow with  fild *ativo* == 1 , it zero to set this record and after it to set 1 in the *ativo* field where the *espera* field is  1 . That is:

When **quantidade == 0** where **ativo == 1**, to set **ativo == 0** and then looking where **espera == 1** and set **ativo == 1**

At the moment I have this trigger, that when the inventory is zero, disables and adds date in the field data_saida

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_setaDataeDesativa` BEFORE UPDATE ON `estoque_folha`
 FOR EACH ROW 
  IF NEW.quantidade = 0 THEN
    SET NEW.data_baixa = current_date;
    SET NEW.ativo = '0';
  ELSEIF NEW.quantidade > 0 THEN
    SET NEW.data_baixa = 0000-00-00;
  END IF
```

I need to create another trigger or can take advantage of this?

Thank you

Comment: you could probably add your logics into the same trigger if it's all in the same table

Comment: your trigger looks wrong, it needs the a semicolon after `END IF` and `0000-00-00` should be in quotes..and it's not a valid date either, if you don't want a date you should set it to NULL